# how to avoid reloading/refresh the page when displaying the post of wp_list_categories

Tags: wp-query, jquery, ajax, get-posts, categories

I have a wp_categories_list in my site and it displays all of my categories. Now when i click one of my category, it displays the posts within that category by refreshing. How can i avoid refreshing/reloading the page?. Can anyone give me some tutorials or a simple code to avoid it refresh/reloading ?

Comment: If you want to load the posts within that category in a div below the category, AJAX might be a good candidate. I'd start here [https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins] and then google your way through any remaining questions you may have.

Comment: hello sir. how can i make it not using a plugin?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You can make a lightweight plugin that lives in your theme to handle AJAX. But you still must activate it in the Plugins Settings page.